# Java Clases y vectores un facturacion

Tags: java, jframe, netbeans-8.2

Soy nuevo en java , estamos realizando un trabajo sobre facturacion donde tenemos que crear la clase y formularios, en cada formulario se coloca la informacion ya sea del cliente, empleado y demas segun se requiera y cuando se va al formulario de facturacion deberiamos poder obtener la informacion del cliente solo con el ID, asi como productos y demas informacion que se guardo en los jframe correspondientes.

CUando vamos a guardar, al parecer si lo hace pero buscar la informacion que se guardo no resulta, aqui esta el codigo que implemente en el main asi como jframe principal e hijos.

jframe principal es frmformulario;

MAIN:

Llamo a cada clase:

```
private static frmformulario formulario;
private static frmCliente Cliente;
private static Cliente cliente[];
private static Departamento departamento[];
private static Empleado empleado[];
private static Ferreteria ferreteria[];
private static Pedido pedido[];
private static Producto producto[];
private static int contador;
```

Para cada clase hay una instancia:

```
   cliente = new Cliente[100];

            for( int i=0; i<100; i++){
                 cliente[i]=new Cliente();

                }
                  contador=0;
```

Metodo de guardar:

```
    public static void guardar_cliente(int c, String n, String d, int t, 
    String co){

cliente[contador].setCedula(c);
cliente[contador].setNombre(n);
cliente[contador].setDireccion(d);
cliente[contador].setTelefono(t);
cliente[contador].setCorreo(co);


contador++;
}
```

Metodo de buscar:

```
public static void buscar_cliente(int bus){

    for(int j=0; j < cliente.length; j++){
        if(cliente[j].getCedula() == bus){
           Cliente.cargardatos(cliente[j]);

        }
    }

}
```

En el jframe hijo ya sea Cliente u otro en el boton guardar el siguiente codigo:

```
    String ce=txtcedula.getText();
    String n=txtnombre.getText();
    String d=txtdireccion.getText();
    String te=txttelefono.getText();
    String co=txtcorreo.getText();

    int c= Integer.parseInt(ce);
    int t= Integer.parseInt(te);

    frmformulario.guardar_cliente(c,n,d,t,co);

    txtcedula.setText("");
    txtnombre.setText("");
    txtdireccion.setText("");
    txttelefono.setText("");
    txtcorreo.setText("");
```

En el jframe facturacion boton consulta:

```
int buscar= Integer.parseInt(txtcedula.getText());
    frmformulario.buscar_cliente(buscar);
```

dentro del jframe facturacion:

```
public void cargardatos(Cliente cli){    

    this.txtnombre.setText(cli.getNombre());
    this.txtdireccion.setText(cli.getDireccion());
    this.txttelefono.setText(Integer.toString(cli.getTelefono()));
    this.txtcorreo.setText(cli.getCorreo());

}
```

Cuando intento usar el boton buscar en el jframe factura obtengo el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at proyecto.frmformulario.buscar_cliente(frmformulario.java:332)    at
>   proyecto.frmCliente.btnconsultaActionPerformed(frmCliente.java:188)
>     at proyecto.frmCliente.access$200(frmCliente.java:12)   at
>   proyecto.frmCliente$3.actionPerformed(frmCliente.java:77)     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Cual es la linea 332?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo ver, es que tu método de cargar_datos

```
public void cargardatos(Cliente cli){

    this.txtnombre.setText(cli.getNombre());
    this.txtdireccion.setText(cli.getDireccion());
    this.txttelefono.setText(Integer.toString(cli.getTelefono()));
    this.txtcorreo.setText(cli.getCorreo());

}
```

es un método no static, en tu llamado que estás haciendo lo haces como si fuera static:

```
    public static void buscar_cliente(int bus){

    for(int j=0; j < cliente.length; j++){
        if(cliente[j].getCedula() == bus){
           Cliente.cargardatos(cliente[j]);       //Acá lo hiciste como static
                                                  //Son invocaciones sin necedidad de crear una instancia de un objeto. 

        }
    }

}
```

Pero el problema no es eso.

Además el error que te muestra indica que la variable a la que intentas acceder **no existe o está null**.

Lo que yo te recomiendo es utilizar una lista de tipo Cliente, para tener un "repositorio" de ellos. Un vector está bien pero tiene límites. En una lista los clientes se buscan por su iteración y se van agregando en orden ascendente.

En caso que no deban usar una lista, entonces un vector de tipo cliente funciona, por cada nuevo cliente se crea un espacio en memoria y así lograrás obtener sus datos sin recibir un NullPointerException.

```
Cliente arrayClientes[] = new Cliente[100];
arrayClientes[0] = new Cliente(cedula, nombre, direccion, telefono, correo);
arrayClientes[1] = new Cliente(cedula, nombre, direccion, telefono, correo);
arrayClientes[2] = new Cliente(cedula, nombre, direccion, telefono, correo);
```